# Do class diagrams contain foreign keys and do you show getters/setters/constructors in the method section

Tags: class, oop, uml

I have two questions about class diagrams I will use the below as an example,

Question 1: Do we use foreign keys in the fact table in a class diagram like we do when creating entity relation diagrams so below the field customerid is also a property/field in the order class.

Question 2: In the methods section of the class diagram do we show the constructor and getters/setters methods.

[image: example class diagram]

Comment: If you have two questions, I think you better actually create two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML lets you decide what you want to show or not:

- In general, the class diagram shows the associations, without explaining how these associations are implemented.  This is different from a crow's foot ERD that can show the link between the table at the key level.
- However, you can model databases in UML using your own stereotypes to document primary and foreign keys or other elements that are not build-in into UML. It's just that there is no universally accepted notation for that.  Here a [popular example](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html).

Regarding the operation compartment (aka "method section", in UML a "method" is called "operation"), we represent indeed the relevant operations.  The getters and setters can be represented.  You can also showw a constructor by preceeding its name with `«Create»`.  But you don't have to show all the methods, if it doesn't help to better understand the design.

*P.S:  You didn't ask, but if you're in DB modelling, you may also think about documenting table triggers  in the operation compartment.*